# Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single compatible version of org.springframework.data.redis.connection.RedisConnection

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, redis

I'd like to work with Redis for manipulating sessions.But I get failure when running the spring boot app.So I guess that this error is coming from maven dependencies especially version conflicts.

I am getting exception after upgrading spring boot version to `2.5.0` from `1.5.9.Release`.
Below are maven dependecies:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-session</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-session-data-redis</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

When I run the spring boot app, I get the belowed error:

```
2021-07-14 16:47:52,711 [localhost-startStop-1] WARN  (AbstractApplicationContext.java:591) - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'enableRedisKeyspaceNotificationsInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/session/data/redis/config/annotation/web/http/RedisHttpSessionConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.data.redis.connection.RedisConnection.getConfig(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/util/List;
2021-07-14 16:47:52,824 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  (ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener.java:136) - 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2021-07-14 16:47:52,841 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR (LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter.java:40) - 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:

    org.springframework.session.data.redis.config.ConfigureNotifyKeyspaceEventsAction.getNotifyOptions(ConfigureNotifyKeyspaceEventsAction.java:74)

The following method did not exist:

    org.springframework.data.redis.connection.RedisConnection.getConfig(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/util/List;

The method's class, org.springframework.data.redis.connection.RedisConnection, is available from the following locations:

    jar:file:/home/bhanu/tomcat/tomcat8/webapps/BlockedNo-blockno/WEB-INF/lib/spring-data-redis-2.5.1.jar!/org/springframework/data/redis/connection/RedisConnection.class

The class hierarchy was loaded from the following locations:

    org.springframework.data.redis.connection.RedisConnection: file:/home/bhanu/tomcat/tomcat8/webapps/BlockedNo-blockno/WEB-INF/lib/spring-data-redis-2.5.1.jar


Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of org.springframework.data.redis.connection.RedisConnection
```

Any help would be really appericiated, let me know if required more information from my side.

**EDIT:**
Removed version for dependencies from pox.xml
so updated dependencies looks like below:

```
<dependency> 
<groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId> 
<artifactId>spring-session</artifactId> 
<version>1.3.5.RELEASE</version> 
</dependency> 

<dependency> 
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> 
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
</dependency> 

<dependency> 
<groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
 <artifactId>spring-session-data-redis</artifactId> 
</dependency>
```

I am getting below error message:

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2021-07-14 18:41:22,473 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR (LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter.java:40) - 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:

    io.gupshup.blockedno.BlockNoSession.sessionRepository(BlockNoSession.java:120)

The following method did not exist:

    org.springframework.session.data.redis.RedisOperationsSessionRepository.<init>(Lorg/springframework/data/redis/connection/RedisConnectionFactory;)V

The method's class, org.springframework.session.data.redis.RedisOperationsSessionRepository, is available from the following locations:

    jar:file:/home/bhanu/tomcat/tomcat8/webapps/BlockedNo-blockno/WEB-INF/lib/spring-session-data-redis-2.5.0.jar!/org/springframework/session/data/redis/RedisOperationsSessionRepository.class
    jar:file:/home/bhanu/tomcat/tomcat8/webapps/BlockedNo-blockno/WEB-INF/lib/spring-session-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar!/org/springframework/session/data/redis/RedisOperationsSessionRepository.class

The class hierarchy was loaded from the following locations:

    org.springframework.session.data.redis.RedisOperationsSessionRepository: file:/home/bhanu/tomcat/tomcat8/webapps/BlockedNo-blockno/WEB-INF/lib/spring-session-data-redis-2.5.0.jar
    org.springframework.session.data.redis.RedisIndexedSessionRepository: file:/home/bhanu/tomcat/tomcat8/webapps/BlockedNo-blockno/WEB-INF/lib/spring-session-data-redis-2.5.0.jar


Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of org.springframework.session.data.redis.RedisOperationsSessionRepository
```

Comment: You have mismatched versions of your dependencies. You should remove the `<version>…</version>` elements from your pom and allow Spring Boot's dependency management to control the versions instead.

Comment: I updated my pox.xml and below is latest one:

  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-session</artifactId>
   <version>1.3.5.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-session-data-redis</artifactId>
<!--   <version>2.5.0</version>-->
<!--   <type>pom</type>-->
  </dependency>

But getting same error message.

Comment: @AndyWilkinson, I updated the question please check now

Comment: You still have a version declared on your Spring Session dependency and it's really old. If you're trying to use Spring Session's Redis support you should depend on `spring-session-data-redis`. If you're trying to use Session's core, you should depend on `spring-session-core`.

Comment: I tried to remove version for `spring-session` dependency but getting compile time error with spring boot `2.x.x` version. I can see latest version for spring-session is `1.3.5.Release` which I used above in pom.xml.
Reference - https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.session/spring-session

Comment: Below function is working with above 3 dependencies and spring boot version `1.5.9.Release`:

 @Bean("sessionRepositoryCustom")
 @Primary
 public RedisOperationsSessionRepository sessionRepository(RedisConnectionFactory factory)
 {
  RedisOperationsSessionRepository sessionRepository = new RedisOperationsSessionRepository(factory);
  // Set the TTL of redis' key, which in turn will expire session when TTL is
  // reached
  sessionRepository.setDefaultMaxInactiveInterval(inactiveInterval);
  return sessionRepository;
 }

Comment: If I use spring boot version 2.5.0 with above 3 depedencies then got last execption pasted in question or if remove `spring-session` dependency then got below compile time error:


'RedisOperationsSessionRepository(org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisOperations<java.lang.Object,java.lang.Object>)' in 'org.springframework.session.data.redis.RedisOperationsSessionRepository' cannot be applied to '(org.springframework.data.redis.connection.RedisConnectionFactory)'

It states that `RedisOperationsSessionRepository` is deperecated.

Comment: The `spring-session` module is really old. It doesn't exist in the latest versions of Spring Session and you should not be using it with Spring Boot 2.x. Instead,  you should be using `spring-session-data-redis`.

As the deprecation message says, you should be using `RedisIndexedSessionRepository` in place of `RedisOperationsSessionRepository`.

Comment: Thanks @AndyWilkinson, it is working fine now after using `RedisIndexedSessionRepository` instead of `RedisOperationsSessionRepository` and removing `spring-session` dependency.
Is there other ways to set `defaultMaxInactiveInterval`, using configuration or properties?

Comment: I am using like this way right now:
        RedisTemplate<Object, Object> template = new RedisTemplate();
        template.setKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
        template.setHashKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
        template.setConnectionFactory(factory);
        template.afterPropertiesSet();
        RedisIndexedSessionRepository sessionRepository = new RedisIndexedSessionRepository(template);
        sessionRepository.setDefaultMaxInactiveInterval(inactiveInterval);